# Unable To Send Multiline Plaintext Email With Mailgun using Ruby

Tags: ruby, mailgun

I am using two files to send messages with Mailgun. They are:

```
email_sender.rb
message_text.rb
```

The code for the first one is:

```
require './message_text.rb'

fromLabel = "Email Guy"
fromAddress = "digital@mail.*****.com"
toAddress = "info@*****.net"
subject = "An Invitation"

cmd = "curl -s --user 'api:key-*****' https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mail.*****.com/messages -F from='" + fromLabel + " <" + fromAddress + ">' -F to='" +toAddress + "' -F subject='" + subject + "' -F text='" + $message + "'"

wasGood = system (cmd)
```

The code for the second file is:

```
$message = "Line One Text."
+ "\n" + "\n" + "And Line Two Text!"
```

When I test sending an email, the message that arrives in my test account inbox is as follows.

```
Line One Text.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the code with `ruby -w`, that is: with warnings enabled, it warns:  `warning: possibly useless use of + in void context`, with the according line number, pointing to:

```
$message = "Line One Text."
+ "\n" + "\n" + "And Line Two Text!"
```

Which is a polite way of Ruby saying: "well, it's not a syntax error, but it does not make sense to me."
Try it with

```
$message = "Line One Text.

And Line Two Text!" # or: "Line One Text.\n\nAnd Line Two Text!"
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working by putting everything on a single line.

```
$message = "Line One Text!" + "\n" + "\n" + "Line Two Text!"
```